# Split a string from a column in pd.series format python

Tags: python, pandas, split

I am new to Python and was trying to do some stuff to do hands on on it.

While doing this I am stuck here.

I have a data in .csv format which I imported to python using

```
data = pandas.read_csv("data.csv")
data.head()

   user  rating      id
0     1     3.5  1_1193
1     1     3.5   1_661
2     1     3.5   1_914
3     1     3.5  1_3408
4     1     3.5  1_2355
```

What I need is from the 'id' column I should get the number which is after '_'.

What I have tried doing is:

```
data.id.split('_')
```

which gave me error:
"'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'split'"

Hence, I made the 'id' column as np.array after reading it from some solution on stackoverflow.

```
s1 = data.id.values
s2 = np.array2string(s1, separator=',',suppress_small=True)
s2.split('_')
```

This gives me output as:

```
["['1",
 "1193','1",
 "661','1",
 "914',..., '6040",
 "161','6040",
 "2725','6040",
 "1784']"]
s2.split('_')[1]
```

gave me:

```
"1193','1"
```

what should I do to get the string after "_"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need vectorized [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with selecting second lists by `str[1]` - also you can check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#splitting-and-replacing-strings):

```
data['a'] = data.id.str.split('_').str[1]
print (data)
   user  rating      id     a
0     1     3.5  1_1193  1193
1     1     3.5   1_661   661
2     1     3.5   1_914   914
3     1     3.5  1_3408  3408
4     1     3.5  1_2355  2355

print (data.dtypes)
user        int64
rating    float64
id         object
a          object <- format is object (obviously string)
dtype: object
```

```
#split and cast column to int
data['a'] = data.id.str.split('_').str[1].astype(int)
print (data)
   user  rating      id     a
0     1     3.5  1_1193  1193
1     1     3.5   1_661   661
2     1     3.5   1_914   914
3     1     3.5  1_3408  3408
4     1     3.5  1_2355  2355

print (data.dtypes)
user        int64
rating    float64
id         object
a           int32 <- format is int
dtype: object
```

Also if need replace `id` column by new values:

```
data.id = data.id.str.split('_').str[1]
print (data)
   user  rating    id
0     1     3.5  1193
1     1     3.5   661
2     1     3.5   914
3     1     3.5  3408
4     1     3.5  2355
```

---

```
data.id = data.id.str.split('_').str.get(1)
print (data)
   user  rating    id
0     1     3.5  1193
1     1     3.5   661
2     1     3.5   914
3     1     3.5  3408
4     1     3.5  2355
```

Comment: Please to mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A couple more options...

***1***
`str.extract`

```
df.id.str.extract('.*_(.*)', expand=False)
```

***2***
`str.replace`

```
df.id.str.replace('.*_', '')
```

---

Both Yield

```
0    1193
1     661
2     914
3    3408
4    2355
Name: id, dtype: object
```